# how to find starting time after the break

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table timetable2 
(
 office_start_time datetime, office_end_time datetime,
 first_break_start_time datetime, first__break_end_time datetime,
 office_start2_time datetime, office_start2_end_time datetime,
 second_break_start_time datetime,second_break_end_time datetime,
 employee_od_start_time datetime,employee_od_job_time datetime
)

insert into timetable2 values
('2013-09-02 08:00:31.773','2013-09-02 12:00:31.773',
 '2013-09-02 11:00:31.773','2013-09-02 11:30:31.773',
 '2013-09-02 12:00:31.773','2013-09-02 18:00:31.773',
 '2013-09-02 15:30:31.773','2013-09-02 16:00:31.773',
 '2013-09-02 09:00:31.773','2013-09-02 10:00:31.773')
```

Result will be 8.00,10.00,11.30,16.00

Comment: what starting time ??

Comment: office_start_time is starting time. I have inserted 8.00 here

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server. have to select the result in sql server

Comment: @user2741663 Check my answer and Reply if that's what you are looking for..!!

Comment: You asking to get only `end time` of all breaks(and `employee_od_end_time`). You have already this values in your columns. If you have more specifications, then show examples with more rows and `personID`....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OFFICE_START_TIME,
EMPLOYEE_OD_JOB_TIME,
FIRST__BREAK_END_TIME,
SECOND_BREAK_END_TIME
from timetable2;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15dcf/2)**

If you need time part only :

```
SELECT 
cast(OFFICE_START_TIME as time) as OFFICE_START_TIME,
cast(EMPLOYEE_OD_JOB_TIME as time) as EMPLOYEE_OD_JOB_TIME,
cast(FIRST__BREAK_END_TIME as time) as FIRST__BREAK_END_TIME,
cast(SECOND_BREAK_END_TIME as time) as SECOND_BREAK_END_TIME
from timetable2;
```

**[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15dcf/6)**

Comment: we should not see the time mannualy. if i insert more than 100 row.then how can be find by using this.pl suggest

Comment: the employee_od_start_time & end_time will be different for each persons.

Comment: number of rows is independent. You can play around the fiddle to insert as much rows you need. Then apply same query and see what happens

Comment: hi i need to find the starting time of after the break & OD.

Comment: hi office working time is 8.am to 6pm. two break times has given in this office time. ie 11 to 11.30 and  3.30 to 4.the employee did od work in the time 9 to 10. now i need to get the result 8,10,11.30,4 by using quiries

Answer (score 0):

**This Code will Do..!!**

```
   select cast(ColumnName as time) [time]
    from yourtable
```

Comment: hi i need to find the starting time of after the break & OD.

Comment: hi office working time is 8.am to 6pm. two break times has given in this office time. ie 11 to 11.30 and 3.30 to 4.the employee did od work in the time 9 to 10. now i need to get the result 8,10,11.30,4 by using quiries –